# Zabbix 5.4 でのSlack通知で障害通知を復旧通知で上書きさせないには

Tags: slack, zabbix

Zabbix 5.4.4 で監視サーバの検証を行っています。

デフォルトで追加されているSlackメディアタイプを使用してSlackへ通知を出していますが
復旧通知が発報された際に障害通知のメッセージ内容を上書きされ書き換えられてしまいます。
Slack上にタイムラインのように障害と復旧の両方が表示されるようにしたいのですが
この挙動は変更可能でしょうか。

変更可能な場合、変更方法についてご教示頂けないでしょうか。
Slack APIアプリ側かZabbix側かどちらで対応出来そうか目星が付いておりません。

Slackに通知を出す為の構成は以下の流れで行っています。

1. Slack APIページからアプリ作成
2. Slackワークスペースのチャンネルへアプリをインテグレーション
3. ZabbixでSlackメディアタイプの設定
4. 通知ユーザの設定でSlackメディアタイプを指定
5. アクションの設定でSlackへのメッセージ送信設定

宜しくお願いいたします。

---

その後、別に稼働しているZabbixバージョン5.0LTSでは、想定通りに障害と復旧が別々に通知されることが分かりました。メディアタイプ設定内スクリプト部分を比較確認してみましたが差分は有るものの挙動が変わりそうな部分を判別することが出来ませんでした。

参考）

【5.4.4のメディアタイプ設定内スクリプト】

```
var SEVERITY_COLORS = [
    '#97AAB3', '#7499FF', '#FFC859',
    '#FFA059', '#E97659', '#E45959'
];

var RESOLVE_COLOR = '#009900';

var SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS = {
    alarm: handlerAlarm,
    event: handlerEvent
};


if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function() {
        var args = arguments;

        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return number in args
                ? args[number]
                : match
            ;
        });
    };
}

function isEventProblem(params) {
    return params.event_value == 1
        && params.event_update_status == 0
    ;
}

function isEventUpdate(params) {
    return params.event_value == 1
        && params.event_update_status == 1
    ;
}

function isEventResolve(params) {
    return params.event_value == 0;
}

function getPermalink(channelId, messageTimestamp) {
    var req = new HttpRequest();

    if (typeof params.HTTPProxy === 'string' && params.HTTPProxy.trim() !== '') {
        req.setProxy(params.HTTPProxy);
    }

    req.addHeader('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
    req.addHeader('Authorization: Bearer ' + params.bot_token);

    var query = '{0}?channel={1}&message_ts={2}'.format(
            Slack.getPermalink,
            encodeURIComponent(channelId),
            encodeURIComponent(messageTimestamp)),
        resp = JSON.parse(req.get(query));

    if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
        throw 'message was created, but getting message link was failed with reason "' + resp.error + '"';
    }

    return resp.permalink;
}

function createProblemURL(zabbix_url, triggerid, eventid, event_source) {
    var problem_url = '';
    if (event_source === '0') {
        problem_url = '{0}/tr_events.php?triggerid={1}&eventid={2}'
            .format(
                zabbix_url,
                triggerid,
                eventid
            );
    }
    else {
        problem_url = zabbix_url;
    }

    return problem_url;
}

function handlerAlarm(params) {
    var fields = {
        channel: params.channel,
        as_user: params.slack_as_user,
    };

    if (isEventProblem(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        var resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }

        result.tags.__message_ts = resp.ts;
        result.tags.__channel_id = resp.channel;
        result.tags.__channel_name = params.channel;
        result.tags.__message_link = getPermalink(resp.channel, resp.ts);
    }
    else if (isEventUpdate(params)) {
        fields.thread_ts = params.message_ts;
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_update_date,
                params.event_update_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source),
                true
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));
        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }

    }
    else if (isEventResolve(params)) {
        fields.channel = params.channel_id;
        fields.text = '';
        fields.ts = params.message_ts;
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                RESOLVE_COLOR,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.chatUpdate, JSON.stringify(fields)));
        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }
    }
}

function handlerEvent(params) {
    var fields = {
        channel: params.channel,
        as_user: params.slack_as_user
    };

    if (isEventProblem(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        var resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }

        result.tags.__channel_name = params.channel;
        result.tags.__message_link = getPermalink(resp.channel, resp.ts);

    }
    else if (isEventUpdate(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_update_date,
                params.event_update_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source),
                false
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }

    }
    else if (isEventResolve(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                RESOLVE_COLOR,
                params.event_recovery_date,
                params.event_recovery_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.getStatus() != 200 || !resp.ok || resp.ok === 'false') {
            throw resp.error;
        }
    }
}

function createMessage(
    event_severity_color,
    event_date,
    event_time,
    problem_url,
    isShort,
    messageText
) {
    var message = {
        fallback: params.alert_subject,
        title: params.alert_subject,
        color: event_severity_color,
        title_link: problem_url,
        pretext: messageText || '',

        fields: [
            {
                title: 'Host',
                value: '{0} [{1}]'.format(params.host_name, params.host_conn),
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Event time',
                value: '{0} {1}'.format(event_date, event_time),
                short: true
            }
        ],
    };

    if (params.event_source === '0') {
        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Severity',
                value: params.event_severity,
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Opdata',
                value: params.event_opdata,
                short: true
            }
        );
    }

    if (!isShort  && params.event_source === '0') {
        message['actions'] = [
            {
                type: 'button',
                text: 'Open in Zabbix',
                url: problem_url
            }
        ];

        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Event tags',
                value: params.event_tags.replace(/__.+?:(.+?,|.+)/g, '') || 'None',
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Trigger description',
                value: params.trigger_description,
                short: true
            }
        );
    }

    if (params.event_source !== '0' || params.event_update_status === '1') {
        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Details',
                value: params.alert_message,
                short: false
            }
        );
    }

    return message;
}

function validateParams(params) {
    if (typeof params.bot_token !== 'string' || params.bot_token.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "bot_token" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (typeof params.channel !== 'string' || params.channel.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "channel" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (isNaN(params.event_id)) {
        throw 'Field "event_id" is not a number';
    }

    if ([0, 1, 2, 3].indexOf(parseInt(params.event_source)) === -1) {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_source" parameter given: "' + params.event_source + '".\nMust be 0-3.';
    }

    if (params.event_source !== '0') {
        params.event_nseverity = '0';
        params.event_severity = 'Not classified';
        params.event_update_status = '0';
        params.slack_mode = 'event';
    }

    if (params.event_source === '1' || params.event_source === '2') {
        params.event_value = '1';
    }

    if (params.event_source === '1') {
        params.host_name = params.discovery_host_dns;
        params.host_ip = params.discovery_host_ip;
    }

    if (!~[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].indexOf(parseInt(params.event_nseverity))) {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_nseverity" parameter given: ' + params.event_nseverity + '\nMust be 0-5.';
    }

    if (typeof params.event_severity !== 'string' || params.event_severity.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "event_severity" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (params.event_update_status !== '0' && params.event_update_status !== '1') {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_update_status" parameter given: ' + params.event_update_status + '\nMust be 0 or 1.';
    }

    if (params.event_value !== '0' && params.event_value !== '1') {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_value" parameter given: ' + params.event_value + '\nMust be 0 or 1.';
    }

    if (typeof params.host_conn !== 'string' || params.host_conn.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "host_conn" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (typeof params.host_name !== 'string' || params.host_name.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "host_name" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (!~['true', 'false'].indexOf(params.slack_as_user.toLowerCase())) {
        throw 'Incorrect "slack_as_user" parameter given: ' + params.slack_as_user + '\nMust be "true" or "false".';
    }

    if (!~['alarm', 'event'].indexOf(params.slack_mode)) {
        throw 'Incorrect "slack_mode" parameter given: ' + params.slack_mode + '\nMust be "alarm" or "event".';
    }

    if (isNaN(params.trigger_id) && params.event_source === '0') {
        throw 'field "trigger_id" is not a number';
    }

    if (typeof params.zabbix_url !== 'string' || params.zabbix_url.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "zabbix_url" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (!/^(http|https):\/\/.+/.test(params.zabbix_url)) {
        throw 'Field "zabbix_url" must contain a schema';
    }
}

try {
    var params = JSON.parse(value);

    validateParams(params);

    var req = new HttpRequest(),
        result = {tags: {}};

    if (typeof params.HTTPProxy === 'string' && params.HTTPProxy.trim() !== '') {
        req.setProxy(params.HTTPProxy);
    }

    req.addHeader('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    req.addHeader('Authorization: Bearer ' + params.bot_token);

    var slack_endpoint = 'https://slack.com/api/';

    var Slack = {
        postMessage: slack_endpoint + 'chat.postMessage',
        getPermalink: slack_endpoint + 'chat.getPermalink',
        chatUpdate: slack_endpoint + 'chat.update'
    };

    params.slack_mode = params.slack_mode.toLowerCase();
    params.slack_mode = params.slack_mode in SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS
        ? params.slack_mode
        : 'alarm';

    SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS[params.slack_mode](params);

    if (params.event_source === '0') {
        return JSON.stringify(result);
    }
    else {
        return 'OK';
    }
}
catch (error) {
    Zabbix.log(4, '[ Slack Webhook ] Slack notification failed : ' + error);
    throw 'Slack notification failed : ' + error;
}
```

【5.0のメディアタイプ設定内スクリプト】

```
var SEVERITY_COLORS = [
    '#97AAB3', '#7499FF', '#FFC859',
    '#FFA059', '#E97659', '#E45959'
];

var RESOLVE_COLOR = '#009900';

var SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS = {
    alarm: handlerAlarm,
    event: handlerEvent
};


if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function() {
        var args = arguments;

        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return number in args
                ? args[number]
                : match
            ;
        });
    };
}

function isEventProblem(params) {
    return params.event_value == 1
        && params.event_update_status == 0
    ;
}

function isEventUpdate(params) {
    return params.event_value == 1
        && params.event_update_status == 1
    ;
}

function isEventResolve(params) {
    return params.event_value == 0;
}

function getPermalink(channelId, messageTimestamp) {
    var req = new CurlHttpRequest();

    req.AddHeader('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');

    var resp = JSON.parse(req.Get(
        '{0}?token={1}&channel={2}&message_ts={3}'.format(
            Slack.getPermalink,
            params.bot_token,
            channelId,
            messageTimestamp
        )
    ));

    if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
        throw resp.error;
    }

    return resp.permalink;
}

function createProblemURL(zabbix_url, triggerid, eventid, event_source) {
    var problem_url = '';
    if (event_source === '0') {
        problem_url = '{0}/tr_events.php?triggerid={1}&eventid={2}'
            .format(
                zabbix_url,
                triggerid,
                eventid
            );
    }
    else {
        problem_url = zabbix_url;
    }

    return problem_url;
}

function getTagValue(event_tags, key) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('(' + key + ':.+)');
    var tag_value = event_tags
        .split(',')
        .filter(function (v) {
            return v.match(pattern);
        })
        .map(function (v) {
            return v.split(':')[1];
        })[0]
        || 0;

    return tag_value;
}

function handlerAlarm(params) {
    var fields = {
        channel: params.channel,
        as_user: params.slack_as_user,
    };

    if (isEventProblem(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        var resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }

        result.tags.__message_ts = resp.ts;
        result.tags.__channel_id = resp.channel;
        result.tags.__channel_name = params.channel;
        result.tags.__message_link = getPermalink(resp.channel, resp.ts);
    }
    else if (isEventUpdate(params)) {
        fields.thread_ts = getTagValue(params.event_tags, 'message_ts');
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_update_date,
                params.event_update_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source),
                true
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));
        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }

    }
    else if (isEventResolve(params)) {
        fields.channel = getTagValue(params.event_tags, 'channel_id');
        fields.text = '';
        fields.ts = getTagValue(params.event_tags, 'message_ts');
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                RESOLVE_COLOR,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.chatUpdate, JSON.stringify(fields)));
        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }
    }
}

function handlerEvent(params) {
    var fields = {
        channel: params.channel,
        as_user: params.slack_as_user
    };

    if (isEventProblem(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_date,
                params.event_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        var resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }

        result.tags.__channel_name = params.channel;
        result.tags.__message_link = getPermalink(resp.channel, resp.ts);

    }
    else if (isEventUpdate(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                SEVERITY_COLORS[params.event_nseverity] || 0,
                params.event_update_date,
                params.event_update_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source),
                false
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }

    }
    else if (isEventResolve(params)) {
        fields.attachments = [
            createMessage(
                RESOLVE_COLOR,
                params.event_recovery_date,
                params.event_recovery_time,
                createProblemURL(params.zabbix_url, params.trigger_id, params.event_id, params.event_source)
            )
        ];

        resp = JSON.parse(req.Post(Slack.postMessage, JSON.stringify(fields)));

        if (req.Status != 200 && !resp.ok) {
            throw resp.error;
        }
    }
}

function createMessage(
    event_severity_color,
    event_date,
    event_time,
    problem_url,
    isShort,
    messageText
) {
    var message = {
        fallback: params.alert_subject,
        title: params.alert_subject,
        color: event_severity_color,
        title_link: problem_url,
        pretext: messageText || '',

        fields: [
            {
                title: 'Host',
                value: '{0} [{1}]'.format(params.host_name, params.host_conn),
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Event time',
                value: '{0} {1}'.format(event_date, event_time),
                short: true
            }
        ],
    };

    if (params.event_source === '0') {
        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Severity',
                value: params.event_severity,
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Opdata',
                value: params.event_opdata,
                short: true
            }
        );
    }

    if (!isShort  && params.event_source === '0') {
        message['actions'] = [
            {
                type: 'button',
                text: 'Open in Zabbix',
                url: problem_url
            }
        ];

        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Event tags',
                value: params.event_tags.replace(/__.+?:(.+?,|.+)/g, '') || 'None',
                short: true
            },
            {
                title: 'Trigger description',
                value: params.trigger_description,
                short: true
            }
        );
    }

    if (params.event_source !== '0' || params.event_update_status === '1') {
        message.fields.push(
            {
                title: 'Details',
                value: params.alert_message,
                short: false
            }
        );
    }

    return message;
}

function validateParams(params) {
    if (typeof params.bot_token !== 'string' || params.bot_token.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "bot_token" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (typeof params.channel !== 'string' || params.channel.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "channel" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (isNaN(params.event_id)) {
        throw 'Field "event_id" is not a number';
    }

    if ([0, 1, 2, 3].indexOf(parseInt(params.event_source)) === -1) {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_source" parameter given: "' + params.event_source + '".\nMust be 0-3.';
    }

    if (params.event_source !== '0') {
        params.event_nseverity = '0';
        params.event_severity = 'Not classified';
        params.event_update_status = '0';
        params.slack_mode = 'event';
    }

    if (params.event_source === '1' || params.event_source === '2') {
        params.event_value = '1';
    }

    if (params.event_source === '1') {
        params.host_name = params.discovery_host_dns;
        params.host_ip = params.discovery_host_ip;
    }

    if (!~[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].indexOf(parseInt(params.event_nseverity))) {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_nseverity" parameter given: ' + params.event_nseverity + '\nMust be 0-5.';
    }

    if (typeof params.event_severity !== 'string' || params.event_severity.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "event_severity" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (params.event_update_status !== '0' && params.event_update_status !== '1') {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_update_status" parameter given: ' + params.event_update_status + '\nMust be 0 or 1.';
    }

    if (params.event_value !== '0' && params.event_value !== '1') {
        throw 'Incorrect "event_value" parameter given: ' + params.event_value + '\nMust be 0 or 1.';
    }

    if (typeof params.host_conn !== 'string' || params.host_conn.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "host_conn" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (typeof params.host_name !== 'string' || params.host_name.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "host_name" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (!~['true', 'false'].indexOf(params.slack_as_user.toLowerCase())) {
        throw 'Incorrect "slack_as_user" parameter given: ' + params.slack_as_user + '\nMust be "true" or "false".';
    }

    if (!~['alarm', 'event'].indexOf(params.slack_mode)) {
        throw 'Incorrect "slack_mode" parameter given: ' + params.slack_mode + '\nMust be "alarm" or "event".';
    }

    if (isNaN(params.trigger_id) && params.event_source === '0') {
        throw 'field "trigger_id" is not a number';
    }

    if (typeof params.zabbix_url !== 'string' || params.zabbix_url.trim() === '') {
        throw 'Field "zabbix_url" cannot be empty';
    }

    if (!/^(http|https):\/\/.+/.test(params.zabbix_url)) {
        throw 'Field "zabbix_url" must contain a schema';
    }
}

try {
    var params = JSON.parse(value);

    validateParams(params);

    var req = new CurlHttpRequest(),
        result = {tags: {}};

    if (typeof params.HTTPProxy === 'string' && params.HTTPProxy.trim() !== '') {
        req.SetProxy(params.HTTPProxy);
    }

    req.AddHeader('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    req.AddHeader('Authorization: Bearer ' + params.bot_token);

    var slack_endpoint = 'https://slack.com/api/';

    var Slack = {
        postMessage: slack_endpoint + 'chat.postMessage',
        getPermalink: slack_endpoint + 'chat.getPermalink',
        chatUpdate: slack_endpoint + 'chat.update'
    };

    params.slack_mode = params.slack_mode.toLowerCase();
    params.slack_mode = params.slack_mode in SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS
        ? params.slack_mode
        : 'alarm';

    SLACK_MODE_HANDLERS[params.slack_mode](params);

    if (params.event_source === '0') {
        return JSON.stringify(result);
    }
    else {
        return 'OK';
    }
}
catch (error) {
    Zabbix.Log(4, '[ Slack Webhook ] Slack notification failed : ' + error);
    throw 'Slack notification failed : ' + error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

本件、解決しました。

https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/slack
こちらの公式ドキュメントに下記記載が有りました。

> 3. Open the added Slack media type and set bot_token to the previously created token.
>    　・You can also choose between two notification modes:
>    　　・alarm (default)
>    　　　・Update messages will be attached as replies to Slack message thread
>    　　　・Recovery message from Zabbix will update initial message
>    　　・event
>    　　　・Recovery and update messages from Zabbix will be posted as new messages

Zabbix側のメディアタイプ設定にて「slack_mode」パラメーターを
デフォルトの「alarm」から「event」に変更したところ
意図した通りに障害と復旧の通知が個別にSlackに表示できるようになりました。

なお、バージョン5.4と5.0の差違という事では無く
どちらもデフォルト値は「alarm」となっており
5.0管理者が構築時に設定変更していたことが挙動の違いの原因でした。